# Text filed of jasper report alignment issue in IE8

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using *iReport* to create *JR* reports, and I would like to know if there is a way to set the text alignment for *IE8*. I have already set `textAlignment="Left"` but it does not work for *IE8*. Right now in *IE8* it display at the center of total size of text field.

My text field is located at Is it any other property *Page Footer* band. Is it any different property present for *IE*? Is any other property present so that my text field automatically resize with respect to total text present in text box?

Following is my code:

```xml
  <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
   <reportElement  x="0" y="0" width="413" height="30">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.td" value="full"/>
    </reportElement>
    <box leftPadding="10"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
        <font size="12"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Created By: "+ $P{CREATED_BY}]]></textFieldExpression>
 </textField>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved ii by some jquery trick. it is not a exact solution but it works for me
Alter jasper report render on jsp page. it structure like this

```
<td>
 <p>
<span> Created By:
</span>
</p>
</td>
```

Using jquery I have find out specific span for "Created by" text. then parent of span i.e

and apply text align property left.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('span').each(function() {
           //alert($(this).html());
           if($(this).html().indexOf("Created By") == 0)
            {
            $(this).parent().css("text-align","left");
        }
        });
});
</script>
```